# Laravel Relationship Structure with Polymorphic Relations

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a few tables like so...

```
FreeLook    
  - id

SignVendor
  - id

PaintVendor
  - id

VendorJob
  - vendor_id
  - vendor_type
  - free_look_id
  - quote_id

Quote
  - id
```

When a `PaintVendor` or `SignVendor` is chosen for a `FreeLook`, a `VendorJob` will be created and it has a polymorphic relationship so that I can use one table for both of the `SignVendor` and `PaintVendor` jobs. So, essentiall, I want to be able to do this...

```
FreeLook::find(1)->signVendorJob // gets the sign vendor job from VendorJob for that freelook
```

Here, I can't use a `belongsTo` relationship because I cannot distinguish between a sign or paint vendor within the query (or at least I don't know of a way)

```
FreeLook::find(1)->signVendor // gets the sign vendor for that freelook
```

The problem is that I am getting the sign vendor through the VendorJob and Laravel doesn't have a `hasOneThrough`

```
FreeLook::find(1)->signVendor->quote // gets the sign vendor quote from VendorJob for that freelook
```

Since a `SignVendor` can have more than one `Quote`, I only want to get the quote related to the `FreeLook`, or `VendorJob`

Am I going to need to write custom MySQL queries for all of these, or am I overcomplicating things, or just missing something?

Thanks for any help you can afford!

Answer (score 0):

you'll use the `morph` relation as mentioned in the [doc.s](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations)

so in the `VendorJob` model

```
// the morph relation 
public function vendorable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}

// the quote relation
public function quote()
{
     return $this->hasOne('App\Quote');
}
```

and in `PaintVendor` model

```
 public function paintVendor()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\VendorJob', 'vendorable');
}
```

and the same for `SignVendor`.
now `FreeLook::find(1)->signVendor` will return a list of all `signVendor` records so you'll have to loop them like:

```
foreach(FreeLook::find(1)->signVendor as $vendor)
    {
        // fetching the quote of every signVendor related to FreeLook num. 1
        $vendor->quote;
    }
```

I hope this helps you.